# Cumulative return calculation with monthly return

Tags: return, maximum-drawdown

I am working on calculate the cumulative return and I have monthly return rate as input. So I found formula of cumulative return:

$$
\text{cumulative} = (1 + r_1) (1 + r_2)(1 + r_3) - 1 
$$

so I used `(df+1).cumprod()-1` in my python code

while when I used the result to calculate maximum drawdown, it shows weird.
[image]
[image]

You can see I got max drawdown at '63' index while its drawdown is very low actually.

and I found some article and tutorial videos written the cumulative return as:
`(df + 1).cumprod()`.

So which one is correct, what should I use to calculate maximum drawdown?

Comment: Hello Shirley and welcome to SE. What's df exactly? if it's the return? If it's the case, then indeed $r = \prod_i (1 + r_i) - 1$ would give you a return. However maybe you want to annualize it. For example, if $r_i$ are annual returns, then $r_\text{annualized} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + r_i) - 1 \right)^\frac{1}{n}$